# Removing RubberBand item in QGIS 2.18.19

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, qgsrubberband

I have QGIS 2.18.18 and 2.18.19 in seperate computers. I use the following script to remove `RubberBand` items. It works in 2.18.18 but doesn't work in 2.18.19

```
import qgis

# Get RubberBands
rbs = [ i for i in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items()
            if issubclass(type(i), qgis._gui.QgsRubberBand) ]

# Remove RubberBands
for rb in rbs:
    if rb in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
        iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(rb)
```

Colored polygons are RubberBand items.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered with that problem after I unchecked some built-in plugins. At first I thought it was about version. I don't know why but the script worked after checking again **MetaSearch Catalogue Client** plugin.

[image]